# Cuda specific error: %s

Tags: c#, .net, cuda, gpgpu, microsoft-accelerator

I'm trying to program with Accelerator using a CUDA target, but I get the following exception:

> Cuda specific error: %s.

My code looks like this:

```
float[] input = { 0.5f, 2f, 5f, 0.1f, 4f, 0.4f };
FloatParallelArray fpa = new FloatParallelArray(input);
CUDATarget target = new CUDATarget();
float[] output = target.ToArray1D(fpa);
```

The exception is thrown on the last line.

How can I fix this?

I've added references to Microsoft.Accelerator.dll and Microsoft.ParallelArrays.CUDATarget.dll, and copied Accelerator.dll and cudatarget.dll to the project output folder. I'm running in Debug x86 and targeting .NET 4.5. My graphics card is a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M. I don't know if this is relevant, but I got an error during CUDA installation saying something about failing to install a driver.

Update: I've reinstalled, and the error didn't appear. The sample CUDA projects seem to work, but I still get the exception when using Accelerator.

Comment: It probably is that the CUDA drivers did not install properly, have you tried to run any of the samples that the SDK provides?

Comment: @ks6g10 I didn't. I just dove right into the C#, since I'm not really interested in the C++ stuff.

Comment: Because as of now, there is no error code given, thus quite hard to determine the cause of the problem. You should try to run any of the samples, to see if the drivers are in fact installed properly.

Comment: I reinstalled, and it seems to have installed fine. It needs a reboot, but I can't reboot now, so I guess I'll try again later and post my results.

Answer (score 2):

This works on my machines

1. NVidia Quadro 4000
2. GTX 680

```
[Test]
public void KendallTest()
{
    float[] input = { 0.5f, 2f, 5f, 0.1f, 4f, 0.4f };
    FloatParallelArray fpa = new FloatParallelArray(input);
    CUDATarget target = new CUDATarget();
    float[] output = target.ToArray1D(fpa);
    Assert.IsTrue(input.SequenceEqual(output));
}
```